# NullPointerException using custom array adapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on my `ArrayAdapter`. I'm getting a value from a database connected to the localhost and When I post the value to the log cat and delete the `textview.settext("something")` my error is gone. But when I initialize the `TextView` and put something in it the error shows again.

Here is my snippet:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final List<String> values;
    //private final List<String> arr;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("List",values.get(position).toString());
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtlarge);
        textView.setText("hahhaha");

        return rowView;
    }

    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.w("LoadImageFromWebOperations",e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

My error is here:

```
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.database_demo.MySimpleArrayAdapter.getView(MySimpleArrayAdapter.java:57)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-09 02:20:47.433: E/AndroidRuntime(1168):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help thanks

Comment: what is line 57 in `MySimpleArrayAdapter.java` ?

Comment: Sorry guys. Im so stupid.. hahaha.. I finaly got it..
I changed this `View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);` 
to this:

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listinflate,null);

Im always confuse of using inflater.. the listinflate file contains the textview while the rowlayout contains the listview. Thats why i got nullpointer cause i use rowlayout.. Thanks to [Vipul Shah][1] i change the parent,false to null.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
```

By

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
```

Comment: @thenewbie Rest of the code looks fine in getView.The last thing i would like you to check is if R.id.txtlarge is present in rowlayout

Comment: AHm yeah hahaha my bad i use Rowlayout. But the textview is in the listinflate.xml not rowlayout.xml.. haha I always got them mix up.. Thanks..

Comment: I cant hahaha I would like to answer my own question but it will take 8hrs.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your `textview` or `rowview` is a null object :-)

Have you tried debugging it ?

*EDIT*

- Guessing `textview` is null, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29 returns null is id ios not found. Have you cross-checked that `txtlarge` exists ?

Comment: At least, you should know which one is null which gives ground for investigation

Answer (score 0):

First you are Using viewholder in a bad way, Second use  `convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);`

```
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

if (convertView ==null ) {

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null);
    // Creates a ViewHolder and store references to the two children views
    // we want to bind data to.
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextView
    // and the ImageView.
    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

// Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtLarge);
holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
```

Comment: why not just bind the `View` when `convertView` is `NULL` ? Outside of `if-else` block you can call directly to the `View` objects. I don't think always try to call `findViewById` is a good idea, cause the search `View` algorithm quite takes time.

Comment: i saw that code already in the some blog some time. Did you copy it?? hehe Peace :)

Comment: @thenewbie I haven't copy it Sir, this is how Design Pattern ViewHolder works, aand stop making comments like these!! It's not funny

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong on your above code in order to run normally. Based on many empty lines, I guess you have tried to deleted some lines, update layout ..blah blah. So I think clean project and re-run it again.

Sometimes, when you try to edit layout and don't clean your projects, it will use the previous build cache, which usually cause `NullPointerException` because the new layout is not updated.

Comment: Yeah i delete some code.. I figure out what causing my problem. But thanks anyway. I didnt know that not cleaning the projects can make a null pointer hahaha.. Thanks for the tip